# Angle at Intersection of Two Lines

Tags: python, numpy, angle

This is a rather simple question, but I'm trying to track down a bug and could use a confirmation of my methods.

Given this example code, how would you calculate the angle at the intersection of the two lines `a` and `b`? i.e., at θ? Please only use `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000
x = np.arange(n)
a = np.ones(n) * 3
b = -0.11 * x - 112
```

I'll post my method in an edit in a day or so, but I'm getting ~29 degrees.

[image]

---

EDIT: here's the solution that got me 29 degrees. Why is this incorrect?

```
def _angle(a, b):
    return np.degrees(np.arccos(np.dot(a, b)/ (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b))))  

print(_angle(a,b))
```

Comment: What are the inputs?  How are you defining `a` and `b`?  These values in your sample code don't seem to define lines

Comment: Your angle is not ~29⁰. Apparently you have used a protractor, some sort of protractor, to measure the angle on the graph, but  the angle on the graph is heavily distorted, because the aspect ratio of the graph is close to 0.1. The angle, measured as shown in the graph, is approximately equal to 6⁰, a good approximation is `180 × 0.11 / π` (it's a good approximation because the angle is small).

Comment: @gboffi I did not use a protractor. That’s why I’m asking this question lol

Comment: Nevertheless, apparently your estimate was derived by an analysis of the angle as shown in the graph.

Comment: That’s my question. How would you calculate the angle at their intersection?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np

n = 1000
x = np.arange(n)
a = np.ones(n) * 3
b = -0.11 * x - 112

angle = np.arctan2(b, x) - np.arctan2(a, x)
angle_degrees = np.rad2deg(angle)
```

Hey, you can use this 'numpy.arctan2()' thing to figure out the angle between two lines in radians. It'll give you the angle at every point along the x-axis. And, if you want it in degrees, you can just use another numpy function to convert it. Just keep in mind, it'll give you the angle between the lines at every point, if you want the angle of intersection, you'll need to use the point of intersection.